# How much of Earth is carbon-based?

Tags: geology

### Description

Carbon ($C$), makes up for the majority of our planet and everything that lives on it. Coal, gems *(any gem)*, plants, and most sedimentary rocks also contain great deals of carbon.

> **Fun fact:** Coal is almost purely carbon; due to it being made entirely of decayed plants and animals.

### Question

I'd prefer a fraction or percentage answer *(ex. about 1/3 or 34%)* Rounded, if you would.

> ***About how much of planet Earth is carbon based?***

Proportion of $C$ to really anything else.

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but your question is a little vague. Are you asking the proportion of carbon atoms to all of the atoms, no matter what molecules they belong to? Or the proportion of pure carbon minerals (such as diamond or graphite)? In the crust or in the entire Earth? Please edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: I'm asking for proportion :D

Comment: of the entire planet

Comment: Mass proportion, probably...

Comment: Hopefully my edit helps clarify what I'm asking for.

Comment: I've edited it so it's easier to understand. Are you able to reopen my question after it's closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**0.07%** of the mass of the Earth is estimated to correspond to carbon atoms (computed from data on [Abundance of the chemical elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Earth) that comes originally from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110928074153/http://quake.mit.edu/hilstgroup/CoreMantle/EarthCompo.pdf) paper)

The following table is from the above link and show the relative abundances on Earth in parts per million of mass:
[image]

The original table in the source [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20110928074153/http://quake.mit.edu/hilstgroup/CoreMantle/EarthCompo.pdf) (which correspond to Chapter 1 in, EARTHQUAKE THERMODYNAMICS AND PHASE TRANSFORMATIONS IN THE EARTH'S INTERIOR) is this one:
[image]